# Generating A-Frame models at regular intervals with unique ids

Tags: javascript, web-applications, lazy-loading, aframe, webvr

I need to generate several objects on page load with **unique names** that includes a method that generates the following code in my html:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#filename" modify-materials position="0 0 !insert location here!"></a-entity>
```

The **!insert location here!** is a z-axis value, which can be positive or negative. As the user moves across the z-axis, I would like it to endlessly generate new objects with location values at intervals of 12 units that are within a range, and unload the objects as they get out of range.
I need to be able to add child objects to each placed model object, and I will need to go back and add (and store) properties to specific instances as well, so including a couple of those in the code to generate at the same time would be nice too.

It needs to be efficient, with as few server requests and user-position checks as possible. Possibly lazy-loading. I am having a breakdown with this seemingly herculean task, I'm sure I'm missing something that makes it easy.

I am willing to use libraries and the like, but prefer the lightest weight option available, even if it means writing more code by hand. (just need to figure out how) PLEASE, YOUR GUIDANCE IS APPRECIATED.
Every time I try and code this up, it gets suuuper bloated, and at some point the code just breaks down and I get lost.

Comment: I recommend using the DOM APIs createElement / appendChild. I recommend reading https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#creating-an-entity-with-createelement and add your code to the question. It will make easier for people to understand where you get stuck and provide concrete solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe is a good option to share your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the recommendation, I will rework my code, and if I get stuck, I will make sure to share my attempt in detail.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that I have gotten farther than I have on the last few attempts already. Thank you again!

Comment: if you wanted to submit the createElement / appendChild recommendation as an answer I would accept that and close the question.

Comment: If I appendChild the scene with data from this object constructor:
   function bound (index){
    this.index = index
    this.xPos = (index) =>{
     var pass = index * 12
     return pass
    }
    this.modelCodeBound (xPos) =>{
     var first = '<a-entity gltf-model="#bound" position="0 0 '
     var second = '"</a-entity>
     var pass = first + xPos + second
     return pass
    }
   }